# Home page is not loading, where in other pages are displaying on the site

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, permalinks, uploads, homepage

My home page is not displaying on the site, but it is showing that the page is loading.
and I have checked all other pages. Everything is working except the home page. Even the posts are also getting published.

Comment: Can you please add more details like Theme, version, and if the project on server then URL.

Comment: https://comicsjournalism.com/ this is the condition of homepage. and we can see other pages https://comicsjournalism.com/lockdown-story-3/ once you go through it.

Comment: Youo need to check your PHP error log, there's almost nothing that can be done by just lookiing at the site. The HTML source just abruptly stops at a hyperlink tag, so a PHP fatal error has happened but no error message. Without you getting the error message from the error log it's impossible to answer or debug this, it cannot be done

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tybl9k

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell

Comment: @AnushaAnamdas the screenshot isn't useful, you need to share the error message from the PHP error log. It is not possible to fix this without that error message, the HTML does not contain the error message.

Comment: Is that  " error 404 " ?